# What is the best way to create (or not) users in a mongodb container?

Tags: mongodb, docker, authentication, docker-compose

I'm setting a mongodb container using docker, and persisting data and logs in volumes mapped into the host. The main idea is to up a mongodb container persisting the data.

But the problem, is that I want to create a mongodb admin user and database user (with less permissions) during the startup of the container and if the container is restarted the users won't need to be created again once the data is persisted.

With respect to the creation of the mongodb container, I found many answers in the stackoverflow and I created a Dockerfile, docker-compose.yml and mongodb.conf. It worked fine.

But I didn't find a clear solution related to the creation of users. There are some javascript codes that can be used to create users in mongodb during the initialization of the containers. But it is not clear what happens (or must be happened) with the scripts after the users were created when the container is restarted so to avoid the container to create the users again.

Dockerfile

```
    FROM ubuntu:latest

    RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -qq -y curl wget gnupg gnupg2

    RUN wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.2.asc | 
    apt-key add -

    RUN echo "deb [ arch=amd64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu 
    bionic/mongodb-org/4.2 multiverse" | tee 
    /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.2.list

    RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y mongodb-org && \
    apt-get autoclean && \
    apt-get clean

    ADD mongodb.conf /etc/mongodb.conf

    ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/mongod", "--config", "/etc/mongodb.conf"]
    CMD ["--quiet"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
    version: '3'
    services:
       mongo:
          build: .
          container_name: mongodb
          image: mongodb_img
          environment:
             - MONGODB_USER="${MONGODB_USER}"
             - MONGODB_PASS="${MONGODB_PASS}"
             - MONGODB_DB="${MONGODB_DB}"
             - MONGODB_ADMIN="${MONGODB_ADMIN}"
             - MONGODB_ADMIN_PASS="${MONGODB_ADMIN_PASS}"
          ports:
             - 27017:27017
          volumes:
             - /data/db/:/var/lib/mongodb/
             - /data/logs/:/var/log/mongodb/
```

Currently, it starts the mongodb container without users and without authentication mapping the data and logs, respectively, into the volumes /data/db and /data/logs.

I want that the container starts with an admin user, a specific database, database user and authentication.
If the container restarts the users and database won't need to be created since the data is persisted.

Answer (score 0):

I did some modifications in the docker-compose.yml and mongodb.conf files, and I made two scripts to create admin and database users. For now, it is working as I expected.

I hope that it can be useful to others and if someone has a different solution be glad to share with us.

docker-compose.yml

```
    version: '3'
    services:
       mongo:
          build: .
          container_name: mongodb
          image: mongodb_img
          ports:
             - 27017:27017
          command: --auth
          volumes:
             - /data/db/:/var/lib/mongodb/
             - /data/logs/:/var/log/mongodb/
             - /data/setup/:/setup
```

mongodb.conf

```
    # mongod.conf

    # for documentation of all options, see:
    #   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

    # Where and how to store data.
    storage:
      dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
      journal:
        enabled: true

    # where to write logging data.
    systemLog:
      destination: file
      logAppend: true
      path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

    # network interfaces
    net:
      port: 27017
      bindIp: 0.0.0.0

    security:
      authorization: "enabled"
```

setup/create-user.js

```
    db.createUser({
        user: "db_username",
        pwd: "db_user_password",
        roles: [
            {role: "readWrite", db:"db_name"}
        ]
    })
```

setup/create-admin.js

```
    db.createUser({
        user: "admin_user",
        pwd: "admin_password",
        roles: [
            {role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin"},
            {role: "readWrite", db:"admin"}
        ]
    });
```

In order to initialize the container I used the command:

```
    docker-compose up -d --build
```

So to create the users run the following commands:

```
    docker exec mongodb mongo admin ./setup/create-admin.js
```

and

```
    docker exec mongodb mongo db_name ./setup/create-user.js -u admin_user -p admin_password --authenticationDatabase admin
```